# WooCommerce require account creation for only some of the products

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a way in which I can make the creation of the account on WooCommerce checkout mandatory only for 1 or 2 of the products?

Does anyone has a bit of code or something for this?

Thank you!

Comment: you can check this plugin: https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-selective-registration/12437597

Comment: You're welcome 